# node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936 throw err; ^

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, npm

```
function SayHello(name) {
    return "hello" + name;
}

const msg = SayHello("alex");
console.log(msg);
```

when I right in terminal node index.js
I get this error I'm not sure what's happening I Think its a path problem (I'm on m1 Mac )

> ahmed@Ahmeds-MacBook-Pro Week2 CSS & some HTML % node index.js
> node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
> throw err;
> ^

> Error: Cannot find module '/Users/ahmed/WebDevCourse/Week2 CSS & some HTML/index.js'
> at Function.Module._resolveFilename >(node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
> at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
> at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
> at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
> code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
> requireStack: []
> }

Node.js v17.2.0

Comment: ```Error: Cannot find module``` maybe you have your ```index.js``` in another folder?

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error when trying to run $node test.js

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936

I put this into the same directory as my test.js file.

npm install --save @polkadot/api

this worked for me on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of possible causes for this problem, but in my case it was because the parent directory containing my React app was named in the format `Next&ReactApps`. The presence of the `&` caused `npm` to not be able to navigate into the React app's root directory and therefore was throwing these `Cannot find module` errors.

To fix this, make sure to remove the `&` from the names of any directories in the path to your applications.

Answer (score 0):

To fix that use the command "yarn add all" in node.js it would install all prefrence using modules

Comment: I don't see any installed dependencies used in his script, and he's tagged that he's using npm.